# Old pages showing through new in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I'm getting old pages left showing through new ones on my Android tablet. This doesn't seem to happen on my phone. The device is a Polaroid Q10.

[image: screenshot].

Comment: Now that I posted the bug report from the device that had the problem, it seems to be working fine. Great work!

Comment: This issue has been reported on MSE, but seems it hasn't been fixed correctly. I think the multiple sites on topbar is a new bug.

Comment: Duh, yeah, that's where I should've posted this. Should I repost it there?

Comment: No need. It's actually okay to report SE app bug on MSO too (SE staff will read it too), so you don't need to repost it on MSE. Btw, [this report on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260498/) is for the rendering error (looks like it's been fixed).